# splitting list and keeping unique identifier for both values - python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, split

I am trying to figure out a way to best map these values to the course name. The results of the data scraped do not have the same values every time. Every time the "Carts" element appears in the list indicates a new course was scraped. After splitting, I am trying to tie the course name to these labels and values to later join to another DataFrame. What would be the best way to do this?

ORIGINAL LIST/MAPPING:

```
['Carts\nYes - $18', 'Clubs\nYes', 'GPS\nNo', 'Pull-carts\nYes', 'Carts\nYes', 'Clubs\nYes', 'GPS\nNo', 'Pull-carts\nYes']

['Course_1, Course_1, Course_1, Course_1, Course_2, Course_2, Course_2, Course_2]
```

CODE:

```
def split_func():
    for r in rentals_list:
        split = r.split('\n')
        print(split)
        temp_rentals_cleansed.append(split)
        

    #FLATTENING LIST
    for sublist in temp_rentals_cleansed:
        for item in sublist:
            rentals_cleansed.append(item)


    rental_label = rentals_cleansed[::2]
    rental_value = rentals_cleansed[1::2]

rental_cleanser()
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Carts', 'Yes - $18', 'Clubs', 'Yes', 'GPS', 'No', 'Pull-carts', 'Yes', 'Carts', 'Yes', 'Clubs', 'Yes', 'GPS', 'No', 'Pull-carts', 'Yes'] #<- rentals_cleansed

['Carts', 'Clubs', 'GPS', 'Pull-carts', 'Carts', 'Clubs', 'GPS', 'Pull-carts'] #rental_label
['Yes - $18', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'] #rental_value
```

EDIT

Solution below worked, when I save the DataFrame to CSV I get the below output. Is there a way to include the course in the dataframe given the solution below?

```
Carts,Clubs,GPS,Pull-carts
Yes - $18,Yes,No,Yes
Yes,Yes,No,Yes
Yes,Yes,,Yes
Yes,Yes,,Yes
Yes,Yes,No,Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# initial data
cx = ['Course_1', 'Course_1', 'Course_1', 'Course_1', 'Course_2', 'Course_2', 'Course_2', 'Course_2']
ax = ['Carts\nYes - $18', 'Clubs\nYes', 'GPS\nNo', 'Pull-carts\nYes', 'Carts\nYes', 'Clubs\nYes', 'GPS\nNo', 'Pull-carts\nYes']

dicCs = {} # dictionary of courses, each course will have a dictionary of values

zz = zip (cx,ax) # merge list to tuple list -> [('Course_1', 'Carts\nYes - $18'), ('Course_1', 'Clubs\nYes'),......]
for p in zz: # each tuple in list
   if (not p[0] in dicCs): dicCs[p[0]] = {} # create entry for this course if not exist
   dicCs[p[0]][p[1].split('\n')[0]]=p[1].split('\n')[1]  # add dictionary entry to this course: 'Clubs\nYes' -> 'Clubs'='Yes' 

print("\n",dicCs)  # show final dictionary (actually dictionary of dictionaries)
   
df = pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe
for c in dicCs:  # each course (Course_1, Course_2)
    for k in dicCs[c]:  # each key in course (Carts, Clubs,...)
        df.at[c,k] = dicCs[c][k] # set value in dataframe using course and key as coordinates

df.index.name = "Course" # set first (index) column name
print("\n",df)  # final dataframe
```

Output

```
               Carts Clubs GPS Pull-carts
Course
Course_1  Yes - $18   Yes  No        Yes
Course_2        Yes   Yes  No        Yes
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! If you have a moment, could you provide some explanation on what each piece of code is doing so I can further understand?

Comment: When go to save it to a csv I get the following:
```
Carts,Clubs,GPS,Pull-carts
Yes - $18,Yes,No,Yes
Yes,Yes,No,Yes
Yes,Yes,,Yes
Yes,Yes,,Yes
Yes,Yes,No,Yes
```

Is there a way to have the course name/link included in the dataframe when saving to CSV?

Comment: I added the Course column header so it should appear in the csv file